# Puzzling Paragrams

Tags: word, letters

Paragrams (the basis of [word-ladder](/questions/tagged/word-ladder) puzzles) are word relations formed by changing a single letter to change the meaning of a word. For example, you can make **l**etter a little **b**etter, **f**ifty more **n**ifty, and l**i**vely very l**o**vely. This puzzle is based on a 6-letter word for which all but one letter can be substituted to form another word. The format is as follows:

- Each row has the letter and the corresponding meaning of a word
- If the letter *can* be substituted in the original word, the meaning will be from the word formed after substitution
- If the letter *can't* be substituted in the original word, the meaning will be from the original word

| Letter | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A confused mess |
| 2 | Ornamental band |
| 3 | Plunder |
| 4 | Pack |
| 5 | Rubber band |
| 6 | Goof |

<sub><sup>Note: please provide all 6 words in your solution!</sup></sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These might be a decent fit:

> ```
>  Jungle - A confused mess
>  Bangle - Ornamental band
>  Burgle - Plunder
>  Bundle - Pack
>  Bungee - Rubber band
>  Bungle - Goof (the original word)
> ```

Comment: That would be it! Fast solve - do you think it was too easy & are there ways to make it better?

Comment: In hindsight, the intrinsic structure of the puzzle makes it so that once you've figured out "Ornamental band (6)" you know the whole word except for one letter; and actually there's only one other letter that position 2 could have been and still make a word. You could make it harder by giving harder clues (e.g. "Egyptian singer? (6)") or by changing the puzzle design (e.g. withholding the numbers 1-6, or replacing a letter _and_ anagramming in each position: "Laundry agent (6)").

Comment: @Quuxplusone making puzzles harder is easy, knowing when to stop is the difficult part. I think OP nailed the difficulty level in this one: there are six doors into the solution, and all of them have locks on. Finding the weakest lock is only easy in hindsight.